# How to make one controller that executes on every page in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'd like to make dynamic navbar with categories for my app (where categories are taken from database and user can always add his own categories). I have many pages in my app and for each page there's a single controller method (let's say). Navbar is displayed on each app page and it contains dynamic data from dabatase. So inside each controller method I would have to return these categories for navbar.

For example:

```
/**
 * @Route("/")
 */
public function firstPage()
{
    return $this->render('file.html.twig', [
        //... the method's data
        'categoriesForNavbar' => $categoriesForNavbar 
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/page")
 */
public function secondPage()
{
    return $this->render('file2.html.twig', [
        //... the method's data
        'categoriesForNavbar' => $categoriesForNavbar
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/another-page")
 */
public function thirdPage()
{
    return $this->render('file3.html.twig', [
        //... the methods's data
        'categoriesForNavbar' => $categoriesForNavbar
    ]);
}
```

This is just an example but the `$categoriesForNavbar` is a variable to which Doctrine returns categories from database that they will be placed in navbar.
So I have to return these categories inside every controller method. I'd like to make it once for every page.

Could you tell me please what is the best practice to make it?
Thank you in advance for answers.

Comment: You could write a custom Twig Extension like descripted here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: Another option would be to embed controller render in the base template like described here: [https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/templating/embedding_controllers.html](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/templating/embedding_controllers.html)

Comment: Thank you all! I've chosen this another option because it seems to be more "clean" for me and it works properly! But are there some big differences between these two ways? Which is a better practice in this particular case?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [KnpMenuBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/index.html)? You can build menus as services. Use the em to fetch the Category[] arays you need to populate your different menus.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try it in the future

Answer (score 0):

try add this to ur navbar.html.twig

```
{{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\ControllerName::firstPage)) }}
```

and then use a custom function without annotations in ur controller

```
public function firstPage()
{
    return $this->render('page.html.twig', [
        //... the method's data
        'categoriesForNavbar' => $categoriesForNavbar 
    ]);
}
```

and render it in a custom page.html.twig

Answer (score -1):

Try the embedding controllers in Symfony, this link can help you : https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/templating/embedding_controllers.html

```
<ul class="nav">
     {{ render(controller('nameBundle:Controller:nameAction')) }}
</ul>
```